# Selenium Webdriver returns empty response even with --ssl-protocol=any and --ignore-ssl-errors=true

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver in Python I am trying to open a https webpage but am getting the error `Resource request error: 2 ( "Connection closed" )` I am ready using the following flags to no avail:
`--ignore-ssl-errors = true`, `--debug = true`, `--ssl-protocol = any`.
I am on selenium 2.47.1 and phantomjs --version returns
2.0.0. Any thoughts on what I can try to fix this?

I am doing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--debug=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])
driver.get("https://tmp.org")
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: can you open that page in a browser?

Comment: Hi Amin. Thank you for the fast reply! I can open it in my browser. Its 'https://tmp.org' ,  the tacoma musical playhouse (a theater).

Comment: Consider editing your question and adding your code snippet. that might help getting better answers

Comment: Thanks Amin. I have added a code snippet per your suggestion

Comment: Try using `TLSv1` as the protocol. it might help

Comment: Hi. I had tried that before ('--ssl-protocol=TLSv1') unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: I surfed some pages and it suggested that using `phantomjs 1.9.8` is the solution if `--ssl-protocol=any` doesnt work.

Comment: Maybe this will help. If I try the url 'https://www.americascarmuseum.org' I get 'Resource request error: 6 ( "SSL handshake failed" )'

Comment: you get this error using `--ssl-protocol = any`?

Comment: Yep @Amin. I ran the code snippet below:
`from selenium import web driver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--debug=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])

driver.get("https://www.americascarmuseum.org")

print(driver.page_source)`

Comment: Did you try 1.9.8?

Comment: Not yet. Going to try it tomorrow.

Comment: FYI - figured this out. Upgrade to Selenium 2.1 . The reason is that 2.1 fixes one issues with webkit.